# Building a Clone of the Higher Lower Game

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I'm trying improve my understanding of React by building a clone of this website: http://www.higherlowergame.com/

Instead of using Google searches I'm using a dataset of Premier League stadiums and their capacities.

So far I've written the following script:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Papa from 'papaparse'

import LoadingSpinner from './components/LoadingSpinner'
import Item from './components/Item'

import './index.css'

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [teamData, setTeamData] = useState([])
  const [teamBank, setTeamBank] = useState([])
  const [topCard, setTopCard] = useState({})
  const [bottomCard, setBottomCard] = useState({})
  const [hiddenCard, setHiddenCard] = useState({})
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCsv = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('./assets/teams.csv')
        const responseText = await response.text()
        const data = Papa.parse(responseText, { header: true })
        setTeamData(data.data)
        setTeamBank(data.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
    fetchCsv()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (teamBank.length === 0) {
      setTeamBank(teamData)
    }
  }, [teamBank, teamData])

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectTeam = () => {
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * teamBank.length)
      let selectedTeam = teamBank[randomIndex]
      console.log(selectedTeam)
      setTeamBank(teamBank.filter((item, index) => index !== randomIndex))
      return selectedTeam
    }

    if (teamBank.length > 0) {
      setTopCard(selectTeam())
      setBottomCard(selectTeam())
      setHiddenCard(selectTeam())
    }
  }, [score])

  const updateCardHandler = () => {
    console.log(teamBank)
    setScore(score + 1)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner />}
      {!isLoading && (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <p>{score}</p>
          <Item
            key={topCard.key}
            name={topCard.Name}
            stadium={topCard.Stadium}
            capacity={topCard.Capacity}
          />
          <Item
            key={bottomCard.key}
            name={bottomCard.Name}
            stadium={bottomCard.Stadium}
            capacity={bottomCard.Capacity}
          />
          <Item
            key={hiddenCard.key}
            name={hiddenCard.Name}
            stadium={hiddenCard.Stadium}
            capacity={hiddenCard.Capacity}
          />
          <button onClick={updateCardHandler}>Higher</button>
          <button onClick={updateCardHandler}>Lower</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

During the first render I would like to populate the three card variables randomly from the `teamBank` object. I want to make sure these are always unique.  After this, every time a user clicks on the higher or lower button I would like for the `topCard` value to be replaced with the `bottomCard` value and the `bottomCard` value to be replaced by the `hiddenCard` value and for the `hiddenCard` value to be randomly selected from the dataset but also be unique from the values which previously occupied the three card variables.

I'm having some issues with state management where the values still duplicate despite the logic in my `selectTeam` function and trying to remove previous used teams from the `teamBank` object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way React hooks like `useEffect` and event handlers work is they batch setting the state and do it all at once when the rest of the logic has run its course. I.e., what happens in your code is the following:

1. `setTopCard(selectTeam())` runs
2. In `selectTeam` `setTeamBank` ***schedules*** an update using ***current*** value of `teamBank`
3. `topCard` is ***scheduled*** to be set to `teamBank[randomIndex]`
4. `setBottomCard(selectTeam())` runs
5. In `selectTeam` `setTeamBank` ***changes*** the value that `teamBank` was scheduled to be set to in (3) to a new one, calculated ***still using the current*** (before filtering) value of `teamBank`, because it hasn't been updated yet
6. `bottomCard` is scheduled to be set to `teamBank[randomIndex]`, which ***may well be the same*** team as in (3), because `teamBank` was still only ***scheduled*** to be updated (filtered), but hadn't been yet
7. The same goes on with `hiddenCard`
8. When the time comes to `set` all states, because of the above, only the last intended update to `teamBank` actually takes place, filtering out 1 team, instead of 3 and potentially setting the cards to the same teams.

What you want to do instead is rather than passing the `teamBank` variable, which is for our purposes "unmutable", into `setTeamBank`, pass an "updater function" (see [MDN doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)).

Besides, you'll want to be sure `teamBank.length` is at least 3, not just non-empty and do it right at the start of your `useEffect`.

Also, your `useEffect` hook does not depend on `score` - instead it depends on `setTopCard`, `setBottomCard`, `setHiddenCard`, `setTeamBank`.

Your new `useEffect` could look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (teamBank.length < 2) return;
  setTeamBank(tB => {
    for (f in [setTopCard, setBottomCard, setHiddenCard])
      f(...tB.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * tB.length), 1));
    return tB;
  })

}, [setTopCard, setBottomCard, setHiddenCard, setTeamBank])
```

THat said, for what you are intending to make, I don't think your code needs 3 states - one array with some push and shift logic would do just fine.